# Is "Suppose X were true , then Y would hold" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, conditionals, mathematics

In mathematical writing, we often see the following construction, that I'm prone to overuse:

> Suppose statement X is true.  Then Y holds.

I'm questioning:

1. The validity of the sequence "suppose, then".  Should "then" be used only with "if" and the likes?
2. The grammar mood used.  Should this read as follows?

> Suppose statement X were true. Then Y would hold.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with either: *were*...*would hold* or *is*...*holds*. The latter is equivalent to *if X is true then Y is true* or *X implies Y*.

Comment: One could argue that 'Suppose statement X were true.' contains two 'not necessarily fact' markers, and thus contains a redundancy.

Comment: Both of your sample sentences (brown background) are fine.  They have a subtle difference.  But they're both just fine.

Comment: Using a counterfactual in the first sentence establishes the context of an imagined world. So it doesn't matter whether you use the conditional mood in the second sentence -- it's understood.

Comment: "Suppose X were true" uses the subjunctive. "Suppose X is true". In contemporary English, 'were' is more and more rare (except in academic circles). They both mean the same thing.

Comment: I agree with @aparente001 that both examples are acceptable. I'd probably use the "were ... would" version in the context of a proof by contradiction, where X really isn't going to be true.  In other contexts, I'd use the indicative version.

Comment: Keep in mind that this stuff is written by mathematicians, not English majors.

Answer (score 4):

Traditionally, the subjunctive is restricted to *counterfactual* statements, where the hypothesis is untrue or unlikely, as in:

> Suppose pigs could fly. Then wolves would starve.

In mathematical statements, the hypothesis is usually not unlikely because it is sometimes true (unless it's something like *"suppose the Riemann hypothesis were false"* or it's the start of a proof by contradiction). Thus you want to use the indicative in a statement like:

> Suppose XYZ is a right triangle. Then XY<sup>2</sup> + YZ<sup>2</sup> = XZ<sup>2</sup>.

In fact, googling "*suppose x were*", most of the results found appear to be the start of a proof by contradiction.

And as far as I know, there is nothing wrong with following "suppose" by "then".

Comment: Thanks!  That is quite interesting indeed :-)  What is the rational for your last assertion, though?  Why would a comma be prohibited?

Comment: Using a comma to join *Suppose ...* and *then ...* looks like a comma splice to me. But looking online, there are a number of grammar websites that allow commas after *suppose...*. I've edited the answer to remove that statement.

Answer (score 1):

This question asks for an assessment of the “correctness” of three examples.  Each example is either a single sentence or a pair of sentences.  The three examples are:

> 1. Suppose statement X is true. Then Y holds. (example 1 from the discussion)
> 2. Suppose statement X were true. Then Y would hold. (example 2 from the discussion)
> 3. Suppose X were true, then Y would hold. (from the title)

Example 1 is both correct and a common construction.

Example 2 is not incorrect, but the use of the subjunctive this way is much rarer than the simple present, as in Example 1.

Example 3 is a comma splice. Many regard this as an error, although it is deemed acceptable by some sources.

Here’s why.

*Suppose X were true*; *Suppose statement X is true*; and *Suppose statement X were true* are all independent clauses.  Each is an imperative clause, instructing the reader or hearer to do (think) something. Each can stand as a sentence on its own. The clauses in the second place in each example, then Y would hold and then Y holds, are also independent clauses.  *Then* is an adverb meaning *"in that case; therefore"*.  *Then* cannot serve as a coordinating conjunction.
Example 3, from the question title, joins two independent clauses with a comma.

The [Oxford Dictionaries](http://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/the-comma-splice) website has the following entry:

> A comma splice happens when a comma inappropriately links two
>   independent clauses...
>
> The comma here may well represent how people say the two clauses out
>   loud. However, in any formal or academic writing, to use it is
>   incorrect...

The comma splice can be healed either by replacing the comma with a semicolon or by inserting a coordinating conjunction after the comma.

> Suppose X were true; then Y would hold.
>
> Suppose X were true, and then Y would hold.
>
> Suppose X were true, but then Y would hold.

The sentences *Suppose X is true.* and *Suppose X were true.* are both invitations to entertain the proposition, X.  There is  a difference of mood in the verbs of the dependent clauses that are complements of the main verb, *suppose*: indicative mood in the first example and subjunctive mood in the second.  About the subjunctive mood, the [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html) notes:

> Although the subjunctive mood is not often used in American English,
>   it is useful when you want to express an action or state not as a
>   reality but as a mental conception. Typically the subjunctive
>   expresses an action or state as doubtful, imagined, desired,
>   conditional, hypothetical, or otherwise contrary to fact.

The Oxford Dictionaries offer the following as definitions of *suppose*:

> assume that something is the case on the basis of evidence or
>   probability but without proof or certain knowledge...
>
> (of a theory or argument) assume or require that something is the case
>   as a precondition...

Given the meaning of the imperative, *suppose*, arguably, the subjunctive contributes nothing to the meaning of the sentence, except possibly to express skepticism about the proposition one is instructed, in any case, to consider.

Within the Google Books corpus of books published in English, the most common single letter variables following *Suppose* are A, X, and P. The following Ngram graphs confirm the relative rarity of the subjunctive following *suppose* relative to the simple indicative.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're confounding the issue with 'that'. Drop it in your searches. Also remove 'statement' from 'statement X' in your answer text to be consistent. Or something. Also, note you can use wildcards on NGrams now. Investigate how that makes things look.